# Chain rule for orders of magnitude

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm looking for something like a chain rule for orders of magnitude. Suppose:

```
y = O(x)
z = O(y)
```

Then:

```
z = O(x)
```

But we can go more generic than this. If p is a polynomial:

```
y = O(x)
z = O(p(y))
```

Then:

```
z = O(p(x))
```

None of this seems like it would be hard to prove. But can we generalise this any further?

Comment: What is `p`? If it is an actual function, your second rule doesn't work.

Comment: @rici Oops, I forgot to say that it is a polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is straightforward. Suppose `p(y) = an y^k + ... + a1 y + a0`. As `y = O(x)`, there is a constant `c` that `y < c*x`. Hence, `p(y) < an*c^k x^k + + ... + a1*c x + a0 = f(x)`. If `c <= 1`, `p(y) < p(x)` as `f(x) <= p(x)`. If `c > 1`, we can say `p(y) < c^k p(x)`. Hence, there is a constant `c' = c^k` such that `p(y) < c' p(x)`. Therefore, `p(y) = O(p(x))`.

Eventually, as `z = O(p(y))`, we proved that `z = O(p(x))`.

To have a more precise proof, you can use a mathematical induction over the degree of the polynomial `p(x)`.

To generalize the case, we should try to find that functions with a specific property which is `f(y) < c' f(x)`, if `y < c x`. One of the big category of the functions is `f(x)` is increasing, and `f(cx) = \Theta(f(x))`. Hence, the transitivity will be satisfied for all of these functions. For example, `f(x) = sqrt(x)` satisfied the constraint, but `f(x) = 2^x` not.

Comment: I feel silly, I should have written z = O(p(y)), z = O(p(x)). But anyway, where is n coming from? The claim is about the magnitude of z in terms of x, not in terms of n

Comment: @Casebash so it is totally different! : )

Comment: @Casebash please see the new solution.

Comment: Thanks for the proof. However, this question wasn't actually about the proof (which I already informally worked through in my head), but about whether any even more general results exist?